# JQuery Prevent Function .click Firing On Every Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click a chat on my site I want the messages to be grabbed from the server so I use a GET request like so :

```
$("#fetchButton").on("click", function(event){
    retrieveMessages();
}
```

and this is what is in the `retrieveMessages` function

```
$.get("PHP/chat.php",
    {
        action:'retrieveMessages',
        last_message: last_message,
        conversation_id: conversation_id
    },
    function(data){
        $("#messages").append(data);
        last_message = $("#messages").find(".aMessage:last").attr("id");
        $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $("#messages")[0].scrollHeight}, 1000); 
    }
);
```

The issue is that if the button is clicked very quickly multiple requests will begin before the last_message is updated, this results in many copies of the same messages being displayed.

What is the idiomatic way to prevent multiple clicks of this button resulting in multiple requests?

Comment: just use a `boolean`

Comment: Why are you using a `POST` to do a `GET`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically in such situation you just disable a button until request is complete. For this you will need to provide a callback function. For example:

```
$("#friendsDiv").on("click", "#aFriend", function (event) {

    // reference the button
    var button = this;

    // disable the button
    this.disabled = true;

    // provide a callback to be invoked when post is done
    retrieveMessages(function() {
        button.disabled = false;
    });
});

function retrieveMessages(callback) {
    $.post("PHP/chat.php", {
        action: 'retrieveMessages',
        last_message: last_message,
        conversation_id: conversation_id
    }, function (data) {
        $("#messages").append(data);
        last_message = $("#messages").find(".aMessage:last").attr("id");
        $("#messages").animate({
            scrollTop: $("#messages")[0].scrollHeight
        }, 1000);

        // execute callback which enables button again
        callback();
    });
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9t8fLdjn/

Comment: No, in this case you can go with something like this http://jsfiddle.net/9t8fLdjn/1/ You add class `diabled` and then you can style the button so it looks disabled (in demo I used Bootstrap, it's not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to disable the button and then enable it after `$.post`

```
$("#friendsDiv").on("click", "#aFriend", function(event) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);  // disable
    retrieveMessages();
});
```

and the `retrieveMessage` function

```
$.post("PHP/chat.php", {
    action: 'retrieveMessages',
    last_message: last_message,
    conversation_id: conversation_id
}, function(data) {
    $("#messages").append(data);
    last_message = $("#messages").find(".aMessage:last").attr("id");
    $("#messages").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#messages")[0].scrollHeight
    }, 1000);
    $(this).prop('disabled', false); // enable it again
});
```

Comment: What will be this in the post callback.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **on** you could use the **one** jQuery function and bind the button again in the callback. Se http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
$("#friendsDiv").one("click", "#aFriend", retrieveMessages });
var retrieveMessages = function(){
   $.post("PHP/chat.php", { 
      ... 
   }).done(function(){
     $("#friendsDiv").one("click", "#aFriend", retrieveMessages });
   });
};
```